# Given the execution of some method in java, is there a way to determine the number of byte-code operations used for that method?

Tags: java, performance, bytecode

Now I realize JIT could throw this for a loop.  What I'm looking for is a way to count the number of instructions for some set of code being executed.

What I have in mind for this is automated testing that detects when some method exceeds some expected number of instructions (i.e. performance regression)

Comment: Depends on your approach. You can do it via JDI; see [`Method.bytecodes`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/com/sun/jdi/Method.html#bytecodes()).

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're looking for. The way to measure a performance regression is to run a profiler and get timing data, not count ops. That said, are you looking for "the bytecodes of a method", or "the bytecodes that are run for a particular execution path through a method"?

Comment: You can dump the bytecodes for a method, but that's just a static count. Otherwise, write your own Java interpreter and embed a bytecode counter. Or, a little more practically, use JDI to get a debug call after each bytecode is executed, then count the calls.

Comment: I would be very dubious of this approach; plenty of genuine performance optimizations would worsen this metric.

Comment: @ Dave Newtown:  the latter  - bytecodes run for a particular execution path.

Answer (score 0):

You can use byte code instrumentation to add to a counter for every byte code operations or add a number for groups.  This is rather complicated and will slow down your code significantly.

Instead I suggest blackbox timing your method externally. Run the method more than 10,000 times so it is warmed up and run it repeatedly for around 2 seconds.  This will give you an idea as to the range of how many repeats you should get, too high or too low could indicate a problem.

Comment: execution times will be hardware dependent, though.  I'm looking to measure performance in an hardware-independent manner.

Comment: I have heard of people doing this for coding competitions. The problem is you will get a number which doesn't mean anything on a real machine. :P